# Determine probaility function of h(z) of the random variable Z = X + Y

Tags: calculus, probability

I have to find the probability function of what I think is the convolution of X and Y
[f(x) and g(y) here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KLzd.png)

X and Y are continuous random variables.

I want to figure out the probability density function h(z) of the random variable
Z = X + Y.

I may know the how to get the convolution, but I don't know how to apply it in this case, or even to know how to go about starting.

Comment: Are the $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables?

Comment: They are random variables, but whether they are independent or dependent I don't know. I'd assume they are?

Comment: If they are independent use this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions just like you think, it is a proper convolution of two r.v.

Comment: If they are not independent, we need more information. We need to know their joint distribution in order to find $Z.$

Comment: This is all the information I have on this. I have the two probability distributions f(x) and g(y) and the other parts presented in the question. How would I go about using the convolution in this case? I don't really understand how to use that formula.

Answer (score 0):

In this case

$$
h(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}x~f(z-x)g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}x~f(x-z)g(x)
$$

where I have used the fact that $f$ is even. Below there's a sketch of the functions $f$ and $g$. From here, you can see that you should consider the cases

> $z < -1$

In this case

$$
h(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}x~f(x-z)g(x) 
$$

Since $f(u) = 0$ for $|u|< 1$ this integral will not vanish for $|x - z| < 1$, that is $x - z < 1$ or $x - z > -1$. For the first case $x < 1 - z$, but since $z<-1$, this would imply that $x > 2$, however $g(x>2) = 0$. A similar argument can be applied for the second interval, the result is

$$
h(z < -1) = 0
$$

> $-1<z<0$

In this case, the integral is

$$
h(z) = \frac{1}{6}(1+ z)^3
$$

(...)

The final result is

$$
h(z) = \frac{1}{6}\left\{ \begin{array}{lll} 
(1+z)^3 && -1\leq z < 0 \\
1 + 3z(1 +z - z^2) && 0\leq z < 1\\
-5 + 3z(7 + z(z - 5)) && 1 \leq z < 2 \\
-(-3 + z)^3 && 2\leq  z \leq 3\\
0 && {\rm otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here I will post answer in the case when we can really have the answer - case of independent $X$ and $Y$.

So we go, $Z=X+Y$ and because of independence we can use convolution formula. It can be easily seen that $Z$ can't be less than $-1$, and greater than $3$.

For $z\in [-1, 3]:$
$$h(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z-t)g(t)dt=\int_{0}^2f(z-t)g(t)dt, $$
the bound of integration has changed to $[0,2]$, because $g(t)$ is non-zero only on that interval. Now we just have to be careful and don't miss the definition of our functions $f$ and $g$.

$$\int_{0}^2f(z-t)g(t)dt= \int_0^1 t\cdot f(z-t)dt + \int_1^2 (2-t)\cdot f(z-t)dt $$

And now depending on $z$:

- $z\in [-1,0]$
  $$\int_0^{1+z} t\cdot (1+z-t)dt $$
- $z\in [0,1]$
  $$\int_{0}^{z} t\cdot (1-z+t)dt + \int_{z}^1 t\cdot (1+z-t)dt + \int_{1}^{z+1} (2-t)\cdot (1+z-t)dt $$
- $z\in[1,2]$ 
  $$\int_{z-1}^{1} t\cdot (1-z+t)dt + \int_{1}^z (2-t)\cdot (1-z+t)dt + \int_{z}^{2} (2-t)\cdot (1+z-t)dt $$
- $z\in [2,3]$
  $$\int_{z-1}^2 (2-t)\cdot (1-z+t)dt $$